Errors when getting the contract instance
I am following a tutorial to create a peer to peer payment dApp on Polygon network. When I attempt to fetch the accounts in the web3 provider and create an instance of the PaymentToken contract, I get an error saying Type 'bigint' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538) const networkId: bigint
const loadWallet = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      const web3 = window.web3;
      var allAccounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      setAccount(allAccounts[0]);

      const web3_ = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

      // The error in the following line
      const paymentTokenData = PaymentToken.networks[networkId];
      if (paymentTokenData) {
        var paymentTokenInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
          PaymentToken.abi,
          paymentTokenData.address
        );
        setPaymentToken(paymentTokenInstance);
        var bal = await paymentTokenInstance.methods
          .balanceOf(allAccounts[0])
          .call();
        setBalance(bal);
      } else {
        window.alert("TestNet not found");
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      window.alert("Non-Eth browser detected. Please consider using MetaMask.");
    }
  };

contract/PaymentToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract PaymentToken is ERC20 {
    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC20("Payment Token", "Pay") {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}


because type of networkId here
 const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

is bigInt. TypeScript does not allow bigint to be used as index type directly. You need to convert the bigint to a string or number before using it as an index. From Mdn docs
const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

// Convert networkId to string
const networkIdStr = networkId.toString();

now you should be alloed:
 const paymentTokenData = PaymentToken.networks[networkIdStr];


In all the established projects, we get the networkId without converting it to string. multiplier-flashloan

your post is talking about typescript. read the error message Type 'bigint' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538) const networkId: bigint

I get the following error when converting networkId to string: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
